Joining 3 tables with 2 aggregate functions
I have 3 tables as below:
JOBS, PARTS and CUTLOG
I am trying to write a query to retrieve the following:
CUSTOMER_NAME , SUM_OF_PARTQUANTITY , SUM_OF_LOGQUANTITY
The SUM_OF_PARTQUANTITY column will be the SUM of PARTQUANTITY in PARTS table where JOBID = JOBS.ID
The SUM_OF_LOGQUANTITY column will be the SUM of LOGQUANTITY in CUTLOG table where PARTID = PARTS.PARTID
I have tired this, which works, but the results of the SUM's is incorrect:
SELECT J.JOBID, J.CUSTOMER_NAME, Sum(P.PARTQUANTITY), Sum(L.LOGQUANTITY)
    FROM JOBS J
    JOIN PARTS P 
        on J.JOBID = P.JOBID 
    FULL JOIN CUTLOG L
        on P.PARTID = L.PARTID
    Group by J.JOBID, J.CUSTOMER_NAME
    

Below is example data and example result. Thank you
Example of data and result

Help us help you - share some sample data, the result you're getting for it, and the result you're expecting

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be massively appreciated.

@Mureinik i have added some more data and expected result now. If you able to help it would be massively appreciated! Thank you

It looks like you're getting a product you weren't intending to get by joining the tables before applying the aggregate sum. Summing first and then joining will solve the problem:
SELECT   j.jobid, j.customer_name, 
         SUM(spq) AS sum_of_partquantity,
         SUM(slq) AS sum_of_logquantity
FROM     jobs j
JOIN     (SELECT   jobid, partid, SUM(partquantity) AS spq
          FROM     parts  
          GROUP BY jobid, partid) p ON p.jobid = j.jobid
JOIN     (SELECT   partid, SUM(logquantity) AS slq
          FROM     cutlog
          GROUP BY partid) c ON c.partid = p.partid
GROUP BY j.jobid, j.customer_name
ORDER BY j.jobid

DBFiddle demo
